# Joining sql tables and count

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Trying to join two sql tables so i can count. Example:

```
id | n_name | n_group    tableA
--------------------
1    Peter    S1
2    Paul     S2
3    James    A1
4    Arty     S2
5    Amy      S2


id | g_name | g_group    tableB
--------------------
1    S1       Leader
1    S2       Leader
2    A1       User
```

I would like to count how many leaders there are in tableA, using tableB as reference?

What i have so far is which i know doesnt work, but i dont know how to join the tables

```
Try
            connect()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(n_group) FROM [tableA].........

            Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            lrd.Read()
            label1.text = lrd("n_group").ToString()
            lrd.Close()
            disconnect()

        Catch ex As System.Exception
            label1.text = "0"
        End Try
```

Comment: . . What is a "leader"?  What does it mean "using tableB as a reference"?

Comment: Your use of `[tableA]` makes this look like a SQL Server question. Also, you haven't shown us your query. Please [edit] your question to give more details about what goes wrong. Line numbers in failing code are especially helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with this query

```
select b.g_group, count(b.g_group) 
from tablea a inner join tableb b on a.n_group = b.g_name 
group by b.g_group
```

You don't need to specify the g_group content but you use it to GROUP BY the result obtained joining the two tables (So if you even have three "Leader" records your query still work as well for any "User" record)

Of course, if you are interested only in 'Leader' records you should add an appropriate where condition like

```
select b.g_group, count(b.g_group) 
from tablea a inner join tableb b on a.n_group = b.g_name 
where b.g_group = 'Leader'  -- >> or use b.id = 1 <<
group by b.g_group
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the number of people in `tableA` who are a `'Leader'`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.g_name = a.n_group
WHERE b.g_group = 'Leader'
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many leaders there are in tableA you don't need tableB as you have the ID's already and you know which ID's are leaders.

```
SELECT count(n_group) AS CountOfLeaders
FROM [tableA] as a
WHERE a.n_group = 'S1' OR a.n_group = 'S2'
```

Your tableB shows S1 and S2 ID's being leaders.

You could even do it without the where clause and use case when instead.

```
SELECT count(case when a.n_group = 'S1' OR 
                       a.n_group = 'S2' 
             then 1 else NULL end) AS CountOfLeaders
FROM [tableA] as a
```

There are so many ways to do this. You can join on the other table and use the `ID = 1` or where `g_name IN('S1','S2')`. It's however you choose to do it really.

Another example referencing tableB:

```
SELECT count(n_group) AS CountOfLeaders
FROM [tableA] as a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.n_group = b.g_name
WHERE b.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query,

```
SELECT COUNT(A.*) FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.n_group = B.g_name
WHERE B.g_name IN ('S1', 'S2')
```